# Extending oversized image ABOVE tile rather than below? ImpactJS

Tags: javascript, image, overlap, impactjs

So I'm currently creating a simple city builder for a school project, we've got the core functionality in place so now we're trying to make things look a little nicer. Since we didn't use an isometric map ( couldn't figure it out with impactjs ), we want to add the illusion of depth by having buildings bellow roads have a bit of overlap.

It's easy enough to implement an image that is slightly larger than the tile it's sitting in, but the image extends below the tile. I'm guessing this has to do with the way javascript or impact loads images by default, anchoring them to the top of the element it's contained in or something.

http://s3.postimg.org/86une19kj/overlap.jpg

In the above image you can see the building is overlapping the road below it. Is there any way of making it do the opposite and extend ABOVE the tile?

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an offset for the animation sheet before declaring the animationsheet in my building entity did the trick.

```
offset:{x: 0, y: 30},
```